# Install gdcm without conda

Tags: python, linux, installation, anaconda

I want to install gdcm on linux. Based on the instructions (https://anaconda.org/clinicalgraphics/gdcm), I have to use:

```
conda install -c clinicalgraphics gdcm
```

However, I can not use conda install because I should not use Anaconda for some reasons. So, how can I install gdcm?

Comment: If you're looking at the page for the library on anaconda.org, it's going to tell you how to use it with Anaconda. Go to the actual homepage for the library in question, and it should tell you how to use it in other ways. (There are a few libraries that _only_ have Anaconda instructions, because they don't test with anything else, build wheel packages, etc. For those packages, you have to either know what you're doing with Python and setuptools, or just switch to Anaconda. But they're pretty rare.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've gone to the Anaconda page for gdcm, instead of to the project's homepage. Of course the Anaconda page tells you how to install it for Anaconda. But it's got a link to the homepage right there near the top:

```
Home: https://sourceforge.net/p/gdcm/gdcm/
```

If you follow the link, the readme refers you to an [`INSTALL.TXT`](https://sourceforge.net/p/gdcm/gdcm/ci/master/tree/INSTALL.txt) file, which starts off with:

> See the wiki page at:
>
> http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Getting_Started
>
> If you are reading this file, it certainly means you do not know how to build GDCM. See:
>
> http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Configuring_and_Building

It's pretty clear that this is a C library that has bindings for a bunch of languages, not a Python library. So, if you're not on a platform that has pre-built packages for it (it looks like that's only Debian and Ubuntu linux), you'll have to have a bunch of prereqs that you don't usually need for Python, but the directions look pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile it from the scratch.

First step, you download from the website `https://sourceforge.net/p/gdcm/gdcm/`

Next step, it's done with `CMake` command

Answer (score 0):

I found using `pip install python-gdcm` from https://pypi.org/project/python-gdcm/ as a working replacement for the conda install.